# Why does my MenuStrip appear in the incorrect Location on first click?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I'm working on a VB Winforms project (although I'm just as fine with a C# solution) and have the following set up:

- I have a ContextMenuStrip on the form, `msCreateReports`
- I have a MenuStrip at the top of the form with one menu item being `Create Reports` and its `DropDown` set to `msCreateReports`
- I have a command button on the form `cmdCreateReports`

Now, for my command button, I have the following code for its `click` event:

```
Private Sub cmdCreateReports_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdCreateReports.Click
    msCreateReports.Show(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y)
End Sub
```

**EDIT (Update / Explanation):**

---

Basically, what I'm looking for functionality-wise is to have this contextmenustrip be able to show up in one of 2 different places, depending on where the user clicks...
If they click on the menu option, the context menu appears as a drop-down on the `Create Reports` menu item **OR** if the user clicks the command button, the menu will apeear as a context menu on the side of the mouse pointer. I want the same menu to be able to appear on either one of these two locations depending on where the user clicks to make this menu appear.

---

Now, my problem is that **only the first time the command button is clicked**, the ContextMenuStrip appears up top by the menu, rather than on top of the command button, as I would like it to.

After the first click, the menu appears in the correct location... What did I do wrong / how can I fix this??

Thanks!!

Comment: can you post some screen shots.?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't because of the work internet policies, but there's unfortunately very little to show - I click the button and the first time, the menustrip appears up by the menubar, the second time it appears by the curson on the button

Comment: Adjust which control on top of which by modifying their properties when the button is clicked.

Comment: @Ramhound, what do you mean by that?? How would I do that?

Comment: @JohnBustos - You don't know how to change what controls are in the `Background` and `Foreground`?

Comment: No... That I do understand and know... I assumed you meant that, but it didn't do anything, so I thought you maybe meant something else... :(

Comment: It's not very clear (to me at least) what that MenuStrip has to do with this button and context menu issue.  I can't reproduce the problem otherwise.  You might have to update your post with more code.

Comment: How are you moving that *one* menu item between the two places?

Comment: Yes - I am moving the SAME ContextMenuStrip to appear in either place... And it does work AFTER the first click on the command button, it's just that first click that shows it on the top menu rather than at the cursor

Comment: The code you posted does not show you moving the menu.  Instead of moving the menu item, make a second menu item and then just show the menu you want.

Comment: ... I'm not sure I understand... Sorry... In my code, I have the contextmenu as the dropdown for the main menu item AND I have code that pops up the contextmenu at the cursor when the button is clicked... I did show that.... My fear with making a second menu is that I would have to reproduce code for its items when all I want is an identical menu in both locations... Maybe inherit it??? Does my explanation make more sense now???

Comment: You have to post code that can reproduce the behavior.  It's also an odd thing to use a ContextMenuStrip on a MenuStrip.

Comment: Have you put in any debug code that shows you what the current cursor position is?  You should also be able to check the current cursor position in either the Opening or Opened event handlers for the control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same problem (I'm using Visual Studio 2010 SP1, and C#). I don't think we did anything wrong, it looks like a Winforms bug to me.

I fixed it like this:

1) I have unset (using the visual designer) the `DropDown` property of the main strip item.

2) I have defined the Opening event on the contextMenuStrip, and the DropDownOpening event on the main strip item like this:

```
private void toolStripMyMenuItem_DropDownOpening(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    toolStripMyMenuItemMyLists.DropDown = contextMenuStrip;
}

private void contextMenuStrip_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    toolStripMyMenuItemMyLists.DropDown = contextMenuStrip;
}
```

And I don't have this problem anymore. Hope it will help you too :-)

Comment: ... That was PERFECT and it solved the problem in 2 lines of code!! !!AWESOME!! and thank you SOOOOO much!!!!

Answer (score 2):

`Cursor.Position.X` and `Cursor.Position.Y` are relative to Form, you need to use the Overloaded method `ContextMenuStrip.Show(Control control, Point pos)`

Example :

```
//control = the control you have added context menu
msCreateReports.Show(control, new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y));
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I believe this to be a bug also as this behavior only happens the first time.  So I force it to open and then close it before the user has a chance to interact with it.  So in effect I use it once, before the user does and then it behaves correctly.  Here is the code I added in the form load method.  My combo box is used for allowing the user to select from a list of printers.

```
        printerToolStripMenuItem.ShowDropDown();
        toolStripComboBoxPrinter.Owner.Hide();
        printerToolStripMenuItem.Owner.Hide();
```

Comment: I used the same conception as you (what inspired me - thanks) but using only context menu methods (type ContextMenuStrip). Every time the context menu to be opened I use the following sequence: Show(), Hide(), Show(). (I had to encapsulate that logic in one common parent user control so that's why I'm doing it on every opening not on form loading).